# Crystal Report ask database parameter Login C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, crystal-reports

Hello I have a question about C# program, I have to make prints with Crystal reports in a C # Software my problem is that when I make printing Crystal reports asks the database login parameters, how can I disable this? thank you

Below I put the picture of the code and error

**Code and Error:**

[image]

**Errore 2 method:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SetDatabaseLogon function

```
Myreport.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password", "server", "dbname", false);
```

If SetDatabaseLogon function not working ...manually assign connection details to each table in the reports

```
ConnectionInfo connInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
connInfo.ServerName = "Driver={Adaptive Server      Enterprise};Server=x.x.x.x;Port=x;";
connInfo.UserID = "username";
connInfo.Password = "password";
TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connInfo;
foreach(Table table in reportDoc.Database.Tables)
{
   table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
    table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName =        connInfo.ServerName;
   table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName =      connInfo.DatabaseName;
   table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = connInfo.UserID;
  table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = connInfo.Password;
   // Apply the schema name to the table's location
  table.Location = "dbo." + table.Location;
  }
```

Comment: then with the first method always ask me the parameters, with the second method gives me the error in the 'image above